# Evernote does not update note if a tag is deleted or added in that note

Tags: evernote, evernote-app-notebook

If I use `noteStore.findNotesMetadata()` to get recently updated or created notes, no note is received if only tag is updated.

```
//sample python code

noteStore = client.get_note_store()
note_filter = NoteFilter()
note_filter.notebookGuid = notebook_id
note_filter.order = NoteSortOrder.UPDATED
updatefilter = 'updated:' + lastsyncevernote.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H')
```

If I update content of that note, then, using  below api's, I get tags attached to that note but not the other way round.

```
noteStore.findNotesMetadata()`
noteStore.getNoteTagNames(access_token, enid)`
```

How can I get updated notes if only tag is updated?

Answer (score 2):

That's by design. The Evernote team has decided that certain note changes will update a note's `Updated` timestamp and certain ones will not.

Changes that do update the `Updated` timestamp:

- Title
- Body/Content
- Resources/Attachments

Changes that do not update the `Updated` timestamp:

- Created
- Deleted
- Active/Trashed
- Metadata on resources
- Notebook (i.e. notebookGuid)
- Tags (i.e. tagGuids)

The only way I know of to really track when tag assignments change is to use `getSyncState` and `getFilteredSyncChunk` which are discussed in [the Evernote Sync API](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/synchronization.php). These methods use the `updateSequenceNum` property, which does get updated when a note's tag assignments are updated.