# Evernote API NoteStore#updateNote modifies note updated time no matter which field is actually changed

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, evernote

By [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320541/evernote-does-not-update-note-if-a-tag-is-deleted-or-added-in-that-note),
if I only modify tag list of a note, it shouldn't be counted as an update. Thus `note.updated` remains the old value.

This is true when I manually add or remove a tag from a note with official client.

### Trying to Do

Programmatically add a new tag to an existing note (titled "test01") while not updating `note.updated`.
Kind of like simulating the behavior of an official client while modifying tag list.

### Python Code Used

It should be directly executable after inserting your own dev token.

```
import uuid
from datetime import datetime

from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient
from evernote.edam.notestore import NoteStore
from evernote.edam.type.ttypes import Tag, Note


def main():
    # create note_store
    auth_token = "<MyDevToken>"
    note_store = EvernoteClient(token=auth_token, sandbox=True).get_note_store()

    # create a new tag
    the_tag = create_new_tag(auth_token, note_store, "complex_")
    print("Tag  (%s, %s) created." % (the_tag.guid, the_tag.name))

    # search for the note
    note_list = remote_search(auth_token, note_store, "intitle:test01")

    # add tag to notes found
    for note in note_list.notes:
        print("Before: %s, tagGuids=%s" % (note.guid, note.tagGuids))
        result_note = tag_note(auth_token, note_store, note, the_tag.guid)
        print("After: %s, tagGuids=%s, updated=%s" %\
              (result_note.guid, result_note.tagGuids,\
               datetime.fromtimestamp(result_note.updated/1000)))
    pass

def create_new_tag(auth_token, note_store, tag_name_prefix="complex_") -> Tag:
    random_tag_name = tag_name_prefix + str(uuid.uuid4())
    my_new_tag = Tag(name=random_tag_name)
    return note_store.createTag(auth_token, my_new_tag)

def remote_search(auth_token, note_store, search_string):
    my_filter = NoteStore.NoteFilter()
    my_filter.words = search_string
    my_filter.ascending = False

    spec = NoteStore.NotesMetadataResultSpec()
    spec.includeTitle = True
    spec.includeTagGuids = True

    return note_store.findNotesMetadata(auth_token, my_filter, 0, 10, spec)

def tag_note(auth_token, note_store, note, tag_guid) -> Note:
    if note.tagGuids is None:
        note.tagGuids = [tag_guid]
    else:
        note.tagGuids.append(tag_guid)

    return note_store.updateNote(auth_token, note)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Result

1. **[As Expected]** New tag is added successfully.
2. **[Not As Expected]** `note.updated` modified. Not only local data but remote data also reflected this modification. I've checked it with official web app.

### Extra 01

Even if I changed `tag_note()` into:

```
def tag_note(auth_token, note_store, note, tag_guid) -> Note:
    # intentionally doing nothing except updateNote()
    return note_store.updateNote(auth_token, note)
```

The result remains the same. It seems no matter which field is changed, `updateNote()` api call will modify `note.updated` field. This behavior is not the same as official client.

### Extra 02

I even tried to implement the same logic using Javascript API. The result remains the same.

### Question

Am I doing something wrong?
Or is it just impossible to do so with Evernote API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
spec = NoteStore.NotesMetadataResultSpec()
spec.includeTitle = True
spec.includeTagGuids = True
spec.includeUpdated = True
```

This will prefill `Note.updated` in the notes returned by `NoteStore.findNotesMetadata`. Then, use the note with `updated` to call `NoteStore.updateNote` and you will see the `updated` field preserves the original value.